# Autodesk Forge Viewer Markup Large Text Gets Cut Off

Tags: autodesk-forge

When loading a 3D model in the Forge Viewer, we are increasing the default markup stroke and text size, like this:

```
proto.onEditModeChange = function() {
    if (this.is2d) {
        this.setStyles(0.0040, 0.02);
    } else {
        var currentStyles = this.core.getStyle();
        this.setStyles(currentStyles['stroke-width'] * 3, currentStyles['font-size'] * 3);
    }
};

proto.setStyles = function (strokeWidth, fontSize) {
    var styleObject = this.core.getStyle();
    styleObject['stroke-width'] = strokeWidth;
    styleObject['font-size'] = fontSize;
    this.core.setStyle(styleObject);
};
```

So we get the default styles for stroke width and font-size and multiply the size by 3, as we think that is a better default size. For 2D files, we have hardcoded a size that works well for us.

The problem we now run into with 3D files is that when adding markup text that contains a [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender), then the descender gets cut off. Here is an example where I wrote "pgqjy":

[image: Example markup]

This problem does not happen with a smaller font size. How do I prevent the text from getting cut off?

We use Forge Viewer 6.*

**Update 1**

Thanks to Bryan for suggesting I edit the size of the markup after it has been created. Unfortunately it does not fix the issue - the text is still getting cut off. It seems like increasing the textbox height just adds more whitespace above the text. This is how I increased the height:

```
proto.onHistoryChanged = function(e) {
    if (e.data.action === "execute" && e.data.targetId > 0) {
        var markup = this.core.getMarkup(e.data.targetId);

        if (markup && markup.type === "label" && markup.currentTextLines && markup.currentTextLines.length > 0) {
            markup.setSize(markup.position, markup.size.x, markup.currentTextLines.length * markup.lineHeight);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increase the textbox size - you can subscribe to the `MARKUPCORE.EVENT_HISTORY_CHANGED` event to capture the textbox after it's been changed and set its size:

**EDIT**: Why not move all the transformation into the event callback so we won't need to piggyback the plugin which tends to seem a bit hacky

```
markupExt.addEventListener( Autodesk.Extensions.Markup.Core.EVENT_HISTORY_CHANGED, e=>{

   const textMarkup = markupExt.getMarkup(e.data.targetId);
   //check 'textMarkup.type' and 'label' is for textbox
   const currentStyles = textMarkup.getStyle();

   // be sure to wrap this in a control flow to check and only set size right after the textbox is first created to prevent interference with changes made by user

   textMarkup.setSize(textMarkup.position, textMarkup.size.x*3, textMarkup.size.y*3) 

   currentStyles['stroke-width'] *= 3, currentStyles['font-size'] *= 3;
   textMarkup.setStyle(currentStyles);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume markupExt is the MarkupsCore extension `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore`, but I get an exception saying it does not have a get method. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Thanks! - unfortunately it did not fix the problem. Maybe I implemented it wrong? (please see my update 1 in the question)

Comment: Why not move all the transformation into the event callback so we won't need to piggyback the plugin which tends to seem a bit hacky - See edit

Comment: Could you try writing some text with descendants in your example, to see if it cuts off the descendant parts? "233" works fine for me as well, as all the text here is "above the line" so to say. I tried changing to set the font-size in the history changed event as well, but unfortunately, that does not change anything :(

Comment: Ok, that is interesting. I guess I will have to experiment some more then, to figure out why it does not work for me. I think the zoom level also interferes with this somehow